# Class "AppBundle\Controller\HomeController" used for service "AppBundle\Controller\HomeController" cannot be found

Tags: symfony

I am using **Symfony 3.4** and when I'm trying to run server there is an error:

> In RegisterControllerArgumentLocatorsPass.php line 68:
>
> Class "AppBundle\Controller\HomeController" used for service "AppBundle\Controller\HomeController" cannot be found.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Update your question with the namespace and class line of you HomeController.  Could be a typo though usually you would get a different error message.  Maybe post the route as well as the psr-4 section of composer.json as well.  And if you have not already, delete then build the cache again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route('/')
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

> Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: [Syntax Error] Expected PlainValue, got ''' at position 7 in method AppBundle\Controller\HomeController::indexAction() in /home/remas/relevium_symfony/src/AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "/home/remas/relevium_symfony/app/config/routing.yml"). Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.)

Comment: @Route("/") single quote was the problem

Answer (score 6):

The same error manifests when a controller extends Symfony's `AbstractController` and does not import it.

Solved by adding the import to the controller:
`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;`

Comment: For anyone landing here: I just ran into this too with a Controller that extended a different Class. The file containing that class couldn't be read by the fpm daemon, resulting in this error as well. Found out by trying to manually include the Controller class. Making the parent class readable solved it.

Comment: once again the error is in front of the screen... thank you!